# Exclude PFObject Sublclass' Attribute to Get Persisted

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working on an iOS app using the native Objective-C Parse API, and I have a subclass of `PFObject` called `MRPlace` which has a number of attributes that will be stored in the parse back-end. However, there is an attribute (Say the attribute is called `isFavorite`) that I would only like to be kept locally (client-side) and thus excluded from being persisted in the database.

I've looked through the documentation and the web with no luck. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish this in swift so I thought I'd share. Say there's an attribute called `streetName`. This is how you'd declare it normally:

```
@NSManaged var streetName: String
```

However, if you omit the `@NSManaged` it works as desired!

```
var streetName: String
```

Comment: I don't think this will persist the data into the Local Datastore.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in knshn's comment, using `@synthesize isFavorite = _isFavorite` for example will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since they won't be stored on Parse, and really won't even be persisted locally (with no Local Data Store,) you should store these values elsewhere.  There's no way to specify local-only keys on a `PFObject`.

Comment: Really? that is a bit surprising. I've used [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) in iOS and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in Java, and they both allowed exclusion of fields. Thanks though :(

Comment: What if he has `@synthesize isFavorite = _isFavorite;` instead of `@dynamic isFavorite`? Then I guess it will not be stored in the database

Comment: Its a pain but yes no way to exclude additional properties in a objc category on PFObject since it mandates using @dynamic.